# How to pass a picklist field from flow builder to lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I am trying to use [this LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example) in my flow builder. The LWC expects an array of objects as input. My goal is to pass in a **picklist** field of an object to the LWC to display the available choices. I looked through the [Configuration File Tags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) , however, I did not see any information to pass in a **"Picklist"** data type in the XML file. Does anyone know if this is possible to do? or are there any workarounds?